# Context Menu in JavaFX Task

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Following this topic [Context menu insight JavaFX Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170062/context-menu-insight-javafx-task) I want to create Context Menu in JavaFX Task. I tested this code:

```
static private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    private static ContextMenu contextMenu;
    private static CountDownLatch menuCreated = new CountDownLatch(1);

    static synchronized void writeString(String s)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(s).append("\n");
    }

    public static BorderPane init(BorderPane bp) throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("***** CALLED");

        Task task = new Task()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {
                writeString("Task started");

                writeString(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is fx thread: "
                    + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        writeString(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is fx thread: "
                            + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
                        try
                        {
                            contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                            contextMenu.setId("Test ID");
                            writeString("Created context menu");
                            menuCreated.countDown();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            writeString(ex.getMessage());
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            writeString("Test");
                        }
                    }
                });

                writeString("Task finished");
                return null;
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();

        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
        item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("About");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");
        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Preferences");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Close");
        item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //flow.getChildren().remove(bp);
            }
        });
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3);

        bp.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event)
            {
                //contextMenu.hide();

                System.out.println("*********************** Shown Context Menu ***!!!!!!!");
                contextMenu.show(bp, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        bp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                contextMenu.hide();
            }
        });

        menuCreated.await();

        return bp;
    }
```

With this code I set Context Menu for BorderPane. When I click with the right mouse button I see the debug message *********************** Shown Context Menu ***!!!!!!! but there is no context menu. Can you help me to fix this code?

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. Why create a Task which simply delegates its work back to the FX Application Thread? You may as well simply do the work in the FX Application Thread to begin with. Why are you trying to create a ContextMenu in a Task anyway?

Comment: Because there is a limitation in JavaFX when I try to create Context menu insight Task https://community.oracle.com/thread/3524256 I want to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: The "limitation" is that you can't create a ContextMenu on a different Thread. But you only need to do things on separate threads if they take a long time to execute, and creating a ContextMenu doesn't take a long time to execute. Why are you wanting to create a ContextMenu inside a Task anyway?